# dnf install or update / upgrade in one command

Tags: yum, dnf

`yum install package` means:

- if `package` is not yet installed, **install** the latest version
- if `package` is already installed, **update** to the latest version

`dnf install package` means:

- if `package` is not yet installed, **install** the latest version
- if `package` is already installed, **don't do anything**

how can I simulate the `yum` behavior with `dnf` ? Note that this is also the behavior for `zypper` and `apt-get`, so only `dnf` seems to have a different implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after looking around, I found the `--best` option:

```
dnf --best install package
```

would always install the latest version.